# Is there a method to have two finger touch in appium?

Tags: java, appium

I need to double tap with two fingers simulataneously on logo to proceed to next screen?

Comment: 2 finger means? double tap??

Comment: Android or IOS?

Comment: With index finger and middle finger you need to double tap on a element. Its for both iOS and Android.

Comment: Please check my solution and let me know. For me it is working fine

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there exists a method to perform a double tab:

```
TouchActions action = new TouchActions(driver);
action.doubleTap(element);
action.perform();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try below code with help of touch action.

Define Mobile element as mentioned below

```
MobileElement mobileElement= (MobileElement) driver.findElement(by);
```

And pass this element to below function.

```
public void tapTwiceOnElement(MobileElement mobileElement) {

        int halfHeight = element.getLocation().getX();
        int halfWidth = element.getLocation().getY();
        new TouchAction(driver).press(ElementOption.point(halfWidth,halfHeight)).release().perform().press(ElementOption.point(halfWidth,halfHeight)).release().perform();
        new TouchAction(driver).press(ElementOption.point(halfWidth,halfHeight)).release().perform().press(ElementOption.point(halfWidth,halfHeight)).release().perform();

    }
```

Comment: This is not working, its getting clicked on different area.

Comment: You have to provide correct **By** locator if it is click some where else.

Comment: If locator is correct but not clicking on correct place then let me know

Comment: Muzzamil, Locator is correct, but its clicking somewhere above required element.
Kindly help me.

Answer (score 0):

this is a Java code for two finger double tap, in case anyone needs it:
Preconditions: you can change withPosition to withElement and x and y values need to be predefined.

```
MultiTouchAction secondTwoFingerPress = new MultiTouchAction(DeviceBucket.getDriver());
    secondTwoFingerPress.add(new TouchAction(DeviceBucket.getDriver())
            .tap(TapOptions.tapOptions()
                    .withPosition(PointOption.point(xPoint, yPoint))
                    .withTapsCount(2)));
    secondTwoFingerPress.add(new TouchAction(DeviceBucket.getDriver())
            .tap(TapOptions.tapOptions()
                    .withPosition(PointOption.point(xPoint1, yPoint1))
                    .withTapsCount(2)));
    secondTwoFingerPress.perform();
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on appium documentation: https://appium.io/docs/en/writing-running-appium/touch-actions/
You can use **MultiTouch** gesture.

Pseudocode example of tapping with two fingers:

```
action0 = TouchAction().tap(el)
action1 = TouchAction().tap(el)
MultiAction().add(action0).add(action1).perform()
```